# How to use Pulumi Output<string> as a string in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, pulumi

I have a basic Pulumi build for keycloak where I set up a realm, create a scope, create a client, and update teh scopes for my client.

```cs
class RealmBuild : Stack
{
    public RealmBuild()
    {
        var realm = new Realm("ExampleRealm-realm", new RealmArgs
        {
            RealmName = "ExampleRealm"
        });
        var recipemanagementScope = ScopeFactory.CreateScope(realm.Id, "recipe_management");
        
        var recipeManagementPostmanMachineClient = ClientFactory.CreateClientCredentialsFlowClient(realm.Id,
            "recipe_management.postman.machine", 
            "974d6f71-d41b-4601-9a7a-a33084484682", 
            "RecipeManagement Postman Machine",
            "https://oauth.pstmn.io");
        recipeManagementPostmanMachineClient.ExtendDefaultScopes(recipemanagementScope.Name);
    }
}

public static class ClientExtensions
{
    public static void ExtendDefaultScopes(this Client client, params Output<string>[] scopeNames)
    {
        var defaultScopeName = $"default-scopes-for-{client.Name.Apply(x => x)}";
        var defaultScopes = new ClientDefaultScopes(defaultScopeName, new ClientDefaultScopesArgs()
        {
            RealmId = client.RealmId,
            ClientId = client.Id,
            DefaultScopes =
            {
                "openid",
                "profile",
                "email",
                "roles",
                "web-origins",
                scopeNames,
            },
        });
    }
}


public class ClientFactory
{    
    public static Client CreateClientCredentialsFlowClient(Output<string> realmId, 
        string clientId, 
        string clientSecret, 
        string clientName, 
        string baseUrl)
    {
        return new Client($"{clientName.ToLower()}-client", new ClientArgs()
        {
            RealmId = realmId,
            ClientId = clientId,
            Name = clientName,
            StandardFlowEnabled = false,
            Enabled = true,
            ServiceAccountsEnabled = true,
            AccessType = "CONFIDENTIAL",
            BaseUrl = baseUrl,
            AdminUrl = baseUrl,
            ClientSecret = clientSecret,
            BackchannelLogoutSessionRequired = true,
            BackchannelLogoutUrl = baseUrl
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is, I am getting this error around my scopes:

```
Diagnostics:
  keycloak:openid:ClientDefaultScopes (default-scopes-for-Calling [ToString] on an [Output<T>] is not supported.

To get the value of an Output<T> as an Output<string> consider:
1. o.Apply(v => $"prefix{v}suffix")
2. Output.Format($"prefix{hostname}suffix");

See https://pulumi.io/help/outputs for more details.
This function may throw in a future version of Pulumi.):
    error: Duplicate resource URN 'urn:pulumi:dev::KeycloakPulumiStack::keycloak:openid/clientDefaultScopes:ClientDefaultScopes::default-scopes-for-Calling [ToString] on an [Output<T>] is not supported.
    
    To get the value of an Output<T> as an Output<string> consider:
    1. o.Apply(v => $"prefix{v}suffix")
    2. Output.Format($"prefix{hostname}suffix");
    
    See https://pulumi.io/help/outputs for more details.
    This function may throw in a future version of Pulumi.'; try giving it a unique name
```

I tried something like this as well `var defaultScopeName = Output.Format($"default-scopes-for-{client.Name}");`, but I can't pass that into the name for `ClientDefaultScopes`

I did look [at the docs](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/inputs-outputs/#outputs-and-strings) to see if anything stuck out as an issue, but I'm clearly missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule number 1 with Pulumi outputs: Anything you return from an `apply()` will still be an Output, even if it looks like it should be a string.

In other words, on this line of code:

```cs
var defaultScopeName = $"default-scopes-for-{client.Name.Apply(x => x)}";
```

`defaultScopeName` is `Output<string>`.

However, the `x` variable in the lambda *is* in fact a string rather than an output.

The other item to note is that the name of a resource (so the first argument) cannot be an Output. So in your code:

```cs
var defaultScopeName = $"default-scopes-for-{client.Name.Apply(x => x)}";
var defaultScopes = new ClientDefaultScopes(defaultScopeName, new ClientDefaultScopesArgs()
{
    RealmId = client.RealmId,
    ClientId = client.Id,
    DefaultScopes =
    {
        "openid",
        "profile",
        "email",
        "roles",
        "web-origins",
        scopeNames,
    },
});
```

because `defaultScopeName` is an Output, this won't work.

You *could* create the resource inside of the `apply()`:

```cs
var defaultScopea = $"default-scopes-for-{client.Name.Apply(x => 
    return new ClientDefaultScopes(x, new ClientDefaultScopesArgs()
        {
            RealmId = client.RealmId,
            ClientId = client.Id,
            DefaultScopes =
            {
                "openid",
                "profile",
                "email",
                "roles",
                "web-origins",
                scopeNames,
            },
        });
)}";
```

however, this may mean that the resource won't appear in any previews (see the note in the [Apply section of the Inputs and Outputs page](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/inputs-outputs/#apply) in the Pulumi docs).

So what's the answer here? it looks like you're setting the `ClientName` to be a string value earlier in the code, so I'd use the same variable that you're setting there.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix and match `string` and `Output<string>` values. Instead, you need to transform any output and append your static list to the list of resolved values:

```
var defaultScopeName = Output.Format($"default-scopes-for-{client.Name}");
var defaultScopes = new ClientDefaultScopes("some-scope-name", new ClientDefaultScopesArgs()
{
    RealmId = client.RealmId,
    ClientId = client.Id,
    DefaultScopes = Output.All(scopeNames).Apply(names =>
        new[] { "openid", "profile", "email", "roles", "web-origins", }
        .Concat(names)),
});
```

Note that `Output.Format` is used for string formatting, `Output.All` is used to convert to `Output<string[]>` and `.Apply` is used to transform the array. You can learn more in [Inputs and Outputs](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/inputs-outputs/).

Comment: this makes sense for the scopes that i hadn't realized would cause an issue, but also need something for `client.Name`. going to look into this in a bit later so might be able to use something similar

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Pulumi only supports `string` types for the name of a resource.
Since
`var defaultScopeName = $"default-scopes-for-{client.Name.Apply(x => x)}";`
is using an output of a resource, `defaultScopeName` is type `Output<string>` and can't be used for the resource name in the line,
`var defaultScopes = new ClientDefaultScopes(defaultScopeName, new ClientDefaultScopesArgs()`

If I'm reading the code correctly, you specify `clientName` and use it to set `client.Name`. So, I would just pass in `clientName` and use that instead of `client.Name`. And, that should work since it's a basic type all the way through.